# How to fix 'ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application' for any package that calls ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, 32bit-64bit, importerror

I'm new to python, and I've been trying to find answers to this error but haven't found any that are helpful so far. I'm running Python 3.6.6 on x64 windows.

`Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

I keep getting an ImportError whenever I try to run any scripts that use packages that call the ctypes module. The specific packages that it's happened with are scikit-learn and astropy. They both installed fine.

I downloaded dependency walker and tried to see if the packages were 32 instead of 64, but they are all 64, my python installation is 64, everything is 64! I literally don't know what the problem is. I'm not sure that ctypes is for sure the problem but I notice that every time I get this error the last thing before it says ImportError is always the line

`from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array`

here is the full error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jdhaa/Documents/Coding/astro tutorial.py", line 1, in <module>
    from astropy.utils.data import download_file
  File "C:\Users\jdhaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\astropy\__init__.py", line 121, in <module>
    _check_numpy()
  File "C:\Users\jdhaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\astropy\__init__.py", line 109, in _check_numpy
    from .utils import minversion
  File "C:\Users\jdhaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Users\jdhaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\misc.py", line 293, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Users\jdhaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Am i missing something? Any help would be appreciated.
By the way, I installed python x64 from the main python website, and all the packages were pip installed globally.

Comment: Does it reproduce if you start an interpreter and simply type that line (or try to import *ctypes*)?

Comment: It reproduces every time I use the interpreter and try to import sklearn. When I import ctypes by itself, however, it doesn't throw the error.

Comment: I just tried figured out that while the interpreter allows me to import ctypes without throwing the error, when I wrote a script containing only 'import ctypes' and then ran it, it threw the same error as before: "%1 is not a valid win32 application.

Comment: In your file, just before the line: `from astropy.utils.data import download_file`, add `import sys` (if not already present) and `print(sys.executable)`, and paste the output.